# Issue with playing audio - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

ok, so I added this to my bot:

```
if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    voice = await client.join_voice_channel(message.author.voice.voice_channel)
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    betterargs = " ".join(args[1:])
    player = await voice.create_ytdl_player('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + betterargs)
    player.start()
```

but when I type !test and with the end of a youtube link in the chat, the bot joins the channel, but it gives me this error

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\server\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "noob.py", line 99, in on_message
    voice = await client.join_voice_channel(message.author.voice.voice_channel)
  File "C:\Users\server\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 3211, in join_voice_channel
```

Anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

That property (create_ytdl_player) has been removed in rewrite versions (1.x) of discord.py. Please check the example from the discord.py github repository for more info. (It has a music bot example that used youtube-dl)